# Automapper's ProjectTo not playing nice with generics

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-11

Using `ProjectTo` with automapper and generics doesn't seem to work well.  I created this mapping:

```cs
CreateMap<ChecklistSoftwareFirmware, OutputDTO>()
    .AfterMap((entity, dto) => {
        dto.ETag = "something here";
        dto.Compiler = new() {
            Name = "foo",
            Version = "bar"
        };
    })
```

If I do this:

```cs
var entity = await _context.Set<TEntity>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.Uid == uid)
    .ProjectTo<TOutputDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Where `TEntity` is my EF Core database model and `TOutputDTO` is my DTO class none of the stuff from `AfterMap` runs. If I instead do this, it works properly:

```cs
var entity = await _context.Set<TEntity>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.Uid == uid)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

var dto = _mapper.Map<TOutputDTO>(entity);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options) shows a list of what is supported by `ProjectTo` and what is not.

`Before` and  `AfterMap` are not supported.

> Not all mapping options can be supported, as the expression generated must be interpreted by a LINQ provider. Only what is supported by LINQ providers is supported by AutoMapper

Supported:

- `MapFrom` (Expression-based)
- `ConvertUsing` (Expression-based)
- `Ignore`
- `NullSubstitute`
- Value transformers
- `IncludeMembers`

Not supported:

- `Condition`
- `SetMappingOrder`
- `UseDestinationValue`
- `MapFrom` (Func-based)
- **`Before`/`AfterMap`**
- Custom resolvers
- Custom type converters
- `ForPath`
- Value converters
- Any calculated property on your domain object